# PHP - recursion example explanation

Tags: php, recursion

I have a recursion example, and I am wondering about a few things. This is the example:

```
    private function menuBuilder($menuItems, $parentId = 0)
    {
        $res = [];

        foreach ($menuItems as $index => $item) {
            $itemParentId = $item->meta->_menu_item_menu_item_parent;

            if ($itemParentId == $parentId) {
                $children = $this->menuBuilder($menuItems, $item->ID);

                if ($children) {
                    $item['submenu'] = $children;
                }

                $res[$item->ID] =  $item;
                unset($menuItems[$index]);
            }
        }

        return $res;
    }
```

And this the `$res` that the function returns:

```
{
    "112": {
        "ID": 112,
        "submenu": {
            "135": {
                "ID": 135,
                "title": "",
                "slug": "135",
                "url": "http://hivnorge.app/?p=135",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            },
            "137": {
                "ID": 137,
                "submenu": {
                    "138": {
                        "ID": 138,
                        "title": "",
                        "slug": "138",
                        "url": "http://hivnorge.app/?p=138",
                        "status": "publish",
                        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
                    }
                },
                "title": "",
                "slug": "137",
                "url": "http://hivnorge.app/?p=137",
                "status": "publish",
                "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
            }
        },
        "title": "Hjem",
        "slug": "hjem",
        "url": "http://hivnorge.app/?p=112",
        "status": "publish",
        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
    },
    "136": {
        "ID": 136,
        "title": "",
        "slug": "136",
        "url": "http://hivnorge.app/?p=136",
        "status": "publish",
        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
    },
    "139": {
        "ID": 139,
        "title": "",
        "slug": "139",
        "url": "http://hivnorge.app/?p=139",
        "status": "publish",
        "main_category": "Hovedmeny"
    }
}
```

Here, I am passing a flat array `$menuItems` with menu items that each have a set `parent_id` field, and the `items` that have `parent_id` set to `0` are at the root of the tree like structure. What I wonder in this recursion method, since I have never made one before, is, when the first element that has a `parent_id` set to something else other than `0`, passes the foreach loop, does the value set in the default argument `$parentId = 0` changes than for the next coming `item` in the `foreach` loop?
So, to illustrate my confusion I will try to explain it with the following example.

So, for example if the first `$item` in the `$menuItems` has a `$itemParentId = 0` , than it passes the condition

```
   if ($itemParentId == $parentId)
```

and calls again the function here:

```
$children = $this->menuBuilder($menuItems, $item->ID);
```

So, I am passing an `ID` of the first `$item`, for example `112` and calling again the function where the `$parentId`  is equal to `112`. Then when the function is called again there, we enter foreach loop and start again with the first `$item`, and since the `$parentId` is now `112` and the `$item parent_id` is `0` we don't pass the condition `if ($itemParentId == $parentId)` and the `$children` doesn't return anything in this round. So, we just end up with

```
$res[$item->ID] = $item
```

But,then I am not sure what happens when the second `item` comes for example, that doesn't have the `parent_id` set to 0, but to the `112`, which is the `ID` of the previous `item`. How do we fill up the `submenu` array when it wouldn't pass the condition

```
if ($itemParentId == $parentId)
```

If the `parentId` stayed `0`

I am not sure, if my interpretation of the flow is correct at all, but that is how I figured it, so I would very much appreciate if anyone could clear this up. 
This is the element in the flat `$menuItems` array:

```
 #attributes: array:23 [
        "ID" => 135
        "post_author" => 1
        "post_date" => "2017-06-23 10:59:47"
        "post_date_gmt" => "2017-06-23 08:59:47"
        "post_content" => " "
        "post_title" => ""
        "post_excerpt" => ""
        "post_status" => "publish"
        "comment_status" => "closed"
        "ping_status" => "closed"
        "post_password" => ""
        "post_name" => "135"
        "to_ping" => ""
        "pinged" => ""
        "post_modified" => "2017-06-29 09:37:49"
        "post_modified_gmt" => "2017-06-29 07:37:49"
        "post_content_filtered" => ""
        "post_parent" => 0
        "guid" => "http://hivnorge.app/?p=135"
        "menu_order" => 2
        "post_type" => "nav_menu_item"
        "post_mime_type" => ""
        "comment_count" => 0
      ]
     "meta" => PostMetaCollection {#243 
        #attributes: array:4 [
            "meta_id" => 326
            "post_id" => 135
            "meta_key" => "_menu_item_menu_item_parent"
            "meta_value" => "112"
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the value of `$parentId` anywhere in the function. If you were, then, since the variable is defined outside the loop, it would change the value.

Comment: But, then how does the second item get in to the block ```if ($itemParentId == $parentId)``` if it's parent id is some number other than 0, and the parentId argument stayed 0? That is what I don't understand, I will try to expand my question to illustrate my confusion with this

Comment: `$itemParentId` is coming from the `$item` itself - it may have a parent associated with it. The `$parentId` parameter is optional, in case you want to get only the `$menuItems` associated with a specific parent. I assume the default parent value of an `$item` is 0 (top level menu items).

Answer (score 0):

The following line calls the method `menuBuilder` with the parent_id of the item in the for loop.

```
$children = $this->menuBuilder($menuItems, $item->ID);
```

But I wonder if the code stops? Because you are not changig the array `menuItems`, so every recursive call runs the for loop with the same menu items.

Comment: yes, that is why all of this got confusing since I did get as a result tree like structure of menu data, when I thought it would just stop because it would loop only with the first element.

Comment: Do you know, how the array `$menuItems` looks like?